# In Cyclic Redundancy Check, how does the receiver knows what the generator polynomial is?

Tags: layer2, errors, checksum

Must the receiver know the generator polynomial in order to detect the errors in the received data?
So how does it know what generator polynomial the sender has used?

Comment: Knowing the polynomial is not enough. You also need the seed value, implementation style (of the LFSR), if the result is inverted and so one. Most standards document the polynomial but leaf out other details ... like Serial ATA :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that you have to know it in advance in order to calculate the CRC.

The correct polynomial depends on the application of the CRC.   For Ethernet, for example, the CRC-32 polynomial is part of the IEEE 802.3 standard.

For you trivia buffs, it's `0x82608EDB`.